# Python pd using a variable with column name in groupby dot notation

Tags: python, list, pandas, group-by

I am trying to use a list that holds the column names for my groupby notation. My end goal is to loop through multiple columns and run the calculation without having to re-write the same line multiple times. Is this possible?

```
 a_list = list(['','BTC_','ETH_'])
 a_variable = ('{}ClosePrice'.format(a_list[0]))

 proccessing_data['RSI'] = proccessing_data.groupby('Symbol').**a_variable**.transform(lambda x: talib.RSI(x, timeperiod=14))
```

this is the error I currently get because it thinks I want the column 'a_variable' which doesn't exist.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'a_variable'
```

Comment: use `df[a_variable]` instead of `df.a_variable`

Comment: the name of the library is *pandas*. Please tag carefully next time. the [pd] tag is for Placement Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this notation below works:

```
proccessing_data['RSI'] = proccessing_data.groupby('Symbol')[('{}ClosePrice'.format(a_list[0]))].transform(lambda x: talib.RSI(x, timeperiod=14))
```